# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Вся опутана узами приличия она тащила себя домой.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, так как *вся опутана приличия узами* — распространенное приложение, стоящее перед определяемым словом:

> Вся опутана узами приличия, она тащила себя домой.

Стоит заметить, что предложение не совсем удачно стилистически. Возможно, его стоит переформулировать.

Правила — [здесь](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Вся опутана узами приличия**, она тащила себя домой.

Обособленный оборот, выраженный кратким причастием и отнесенный к личному местоимению.

1) § 52. Всегда выделяются запятыми определения, выраженные **краткими прилагательными или страдательными причастиями.** Они могут занимать любое положение по отношению к определяемому слову: В привычный час пробуждена, вставала при свечах она (П.); Овеян вещею дремотой, полураздетый лес грустит (Тютч.);http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=135

2) 3. Нераспространенные определения, относящиеся **к личным местоимениям,** обособляются. Они могут стоять перед ними, после них или отделяться от них другими членами предложения. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118